# please tell how to use if statement with CASE condition in mysql 2005

Tags: mysql, if-statement, case

```
Table :-Person
Column:-day_phone, alt_phone    ,Home_phone
```

Condition:-If day_phone is null then alt_phone
If no data in both then replicate Home_phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use case when   and AND operator

```
  select Person
  , case when day_phone is null then alt_phone
        when day_phone is null and lt_phone is null then Home_phone
    end
  from my_table
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [COALESCE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function that will return the first non-null value:

```
select coalesce(day_phone, alt_phone, Home_phone)
from person
```